# How do I save a file to a subdirectory in InternalStorage

Tags: android

This is how I save files to InternalStorage

```
public static boolean saveInputStreamToInternalStorageFile(Context context, String filename, byte[] dataToWrite, Context ctx) {
    FileOutputStream fos;
    try {
        fos = new FileOutputStream(context.getFilesDir() + File.separator + filename);
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
        oos.writeObject(dataToWrite);
        oos.close();
        return true;
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
}
```

How do I change that code, so that files are now saved into a subdirectory of that folder, called "media/"?

Comment: you want to save the file into the media directory of device ?

Comment: No, I want to save the file into the app-private, InternalStorage, in a custom folder, called media. Or whatever else name

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace:

```
fos = new FileOutputStream(context.getFilesDir() + File.separator + filename);
```

with:

```
File media=new File(context.getFilesDir(), "media");

media.mkdirs();

fos = new FileOutputStream(new File(media, filename));
```